# Target content added dynamically into the Dom with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to target a button that I added into the dom with jquery, but selectors are not able to find it.

I already tried to target it with find &

```
  $('.js-action-edit').on('change', $('.edit-action'), function (){
          console.log(this)
          })}
```

`<div class='edit-action'>` was a response of this ajax request

```
success:function (response) {
                                $('.js-action-edit').html(response)
                            }
```

Comment: your classes are mismatch edit-action edit action

Comment: sorry its a miss typing of mine, i did not make a mistake of that type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `DOMSubtreeModified` with binding

```js
$('.js-action-edit').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
  console.log($(".edit-action").text());
  $( ".edit-action" ).click(function() {
    alert( "click() called." );
  });
});

function test(response) 
{
    $('.js-action-edit').html(response)
}
test("<div class='edit-action'>deneme</div>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='js-action-edit'></div>
```

Comment: it is depreciated :o  is it a good practice to work with it ?

Comment: you can use on rather than bind for newer version. Main thing is DOMSubtreeModified is used to detect html changes

Comment: Hey again, do you know how  i  can attach a listener to this .edit-action ?

Comment: What kind of listenere do you want to attach ?

Comment: A click listener

Answer (score 0):

You are appending it with edit action but searching with .edit-action.

If that is not a typo this might be the problem.

If edit and action are two different classes try $(".edit.action")

Comment: sorry its a miss typing of mine